# httpd service stop working, after i restart the service? any idea?

Tags: apache, openstack, centos7, httpd.conf, systemctl

systemctl restart httpd.service
when i execute that command httpd cannot restart

systemctl status httpd.service
shows

```
   [root@openstack ~]# systemctl status httpd.service
â—� httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           â””â”€openstack-dashboard.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-10-27 18:11:35 WIB; 10s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 14032 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 14029 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 13983 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/python /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/manage.py compress --force (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13959 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/python /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 14029 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 27 18:11:21 openstack.localdomain python[13959]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/modal/delete-modal.service.js'
Oct 27 18:11:21 openstack.localdomain python[13959]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/modal/delete-modal.service.spec.js'
Oct 27 18:11:21 openstack.localdomain python[13959]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/modal/modal.module.js'
Oct 27 18:11:21 openstack.localdomain python[13959]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/modal/simple-modal.controller.js'
Oct 27 18:11:21 openstack.localdomain python[13959]: Copying '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/horizon/static/framework/widgets/modal/simple-modal.html'
Oct 27 18:11:35 openstack.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 27 18:11:35 openstack.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 27 18:11:35 openstack.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 27 18:11:35 openstack.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Oct 27 18:11:35 openstack.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of journalctl -xe

Answer (score 1):

Your status reveals that the service failed for some reason. There could be a million reasons for this, but my money is on a syntax error in the configuration file.

Try running:

```
httpd -t
```

That will either tell you that the syntax is bad and what to fix, or let you know you need to look for a different answer.